# Estimated time to make website work in safari/firefox

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, safari, web, cross-browser

I have a website that was originally designed for enclosed intranet use under IE 7/8 and is now needing to be running on the web, which means making adjustments for firefox, safari and chrome.

The problem is that I'm not too great at time estimating and am looking for advice on what to expect when making the site cross browser compatible. Firefox dev tools is telling me is that there's several CSS tags such as * overflow-x and filter that are not supported.

How differently do safari and chrome render sites from IE and firefox?

Its an HTML, CSS, Javascript, and ASP.net website.

Any insight you have to offer will be appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how well/badly written the site was in the first place.

First question: Is the site rendered in standards mode or quirks mode? If it's in quirks mode, then double your estimates.

Second question: How much Javascript do you have? And are you using jQuery or any other library? If you have a lot of Javascript code, and it isn't using a good library, then the odds are you'll have a fair bit of work to do.

Re the specific CSS you pointed out:

`* overflow-x` - The star here is an IE-specific hack; not sure why it's in there if the site was only for IE in the first place, but it won't affect any other browsers.

`filter` - this is an IE-specific style, which is used for a variety of special effects, including opacity, rotation, and a bunch of other stuff. Most (if not all) of it can be done 
easily enough in other browsers using standard CSS, but you'll have to convert it all manually. Work out what it's doing, then google the CSS standard way of doing it.

Comment: Thank's luckily the site isn't rendering in quirks mode so that's good, but due to restrictions the javascript is all hand written, most of it's pretty simple stuff.